# Is refractive index a property of the material or the light ray?

Tags: optics, refraction, polarization

Why does it vary for e-ray and o-ray in nicol prism?

Comment: Welcome on the Physics SE! What are "e-ray" and "o-ray"?

Comment: @peterh, the OP is very likely referring to *extraordinary ray* and *ordinary ray*.  See, for example, this section in the Wikipedia article [Birefringence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birefringence#Uniaxial_materials):   *"For any ray direction there is a linear polarization direction perpendicular to the optic axis, and this is called an ordinary ray. However, for ray directions not parallel to the optic axis, the polarization direction perpendicular to the ordinary ray's polarization will be partly in the direction of the optic axis, and this is called an extraordinary ray"*

Comment: Refraction is the result of an interaction between the material and the light. Both affect it.

In the case of visible light, the dependence on the light ray is typically negligible in the daily practice, although it can cause [interesting effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration).